# multivariable calculus - Proving that this limit exists with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit:

$\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \cfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}$

According to my book the limit is supposed to exist and be equal to 0, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

First, I try to approach it from two different directions, I'll skip this and say that I tried 3 different directions and got 0 everytime. Now onto polar coordinates:

$\lim \limits_{\rho \to 0} \cfrac{\rho cos^2 \theta \rho^2sin^2\theta}{\rho^2cos^2\theta+\rho^4sin^4\theta} = \lim \limits_{\rho \to 0} \cfrac{\rho^4cos^2\theta sin^2\theta}{\rho^2(cos^2\theta+\rho^2sin^4\theta)}$

Simplifying the above expression:

$\lim \limits_{\rho \to 0} \cfrac{\rho^2cos^2\theta sin^2\theta}{cos^2\theta+r^2sin^4\theta}$

Now, when $\rho \to 0$ the above function is dependant on theta, and even though the numerator tends to $0$ there's the chance of $\theta = k\pi-\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ meaning that we'd end up with $cos^2\theta = 0$ therefor we'd be in a $0/0$ situation. Because of that, the above limit is dependant on $\theta$ and not $\rho$, and that means that the function will assume different values on different directions, meaning that the limit does not exist, but according to my textbook the limit is 0. I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hint: you have 2 cases: the limit when $\cos \theta \neq 0$, which is easy to compute; and the case when $\cos \theta = 0$, which is also easy to compute.

Comment: I am writing an answer, I request you to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up till the quotient $\frac{\rho^2 \cos^2 \theta\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta + \rho^2\sin^4 \theta}$ you are fine.

> Now when $\rho \to 0$ the above function is dependent on $\theta$.

All right, but the dependency is not good enough to prevent the limit being zero!

> there is a change of a $0/0$ at $k\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Indeed, note that at such values of $\theta$, the denominator is not zero because the sine term is not zero! Whatever path we approach $(0,0)$ from, the denominator cannot be zero, because one of the two terms will always be non-zero.

> The function will assume different values in different directions, meaning that the limit does not exist.

Once again, *not different enough to prevent convergence to zero*. Yes, it behaves "very differently" if we approach along the lines $\theta = 15^\circ$ and $75^\circ$, but it doesn't matter : convergence to zero will happen.

The point is, that you haven't done anything wrong, but just panicked, thinking that the function could do different things for different $\theta$. Yes, it does do different things, but near $(0,0)$ those things aren't far off each other. What's the reason?

What you've got to see is this :*what is the dominant term* of the expression? Which term of the expression exerts the most influence on  the expression when your point is close to $(0,0)$?

Well, $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are always confined to $[-1,1]$, so their behaviour is always limited, in that you can always bound their behaviour by the constants $-1$ and $1$. Let us use this fact.

How do we use it? Let us make a small transformation, where we take the $\rho^2$ to the denominator.
$$
\frac{\rho^2 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta  + \rho^2 \sin^4 \theta} = \frac{\cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta}{\sin^4 \theta + \color{blue}{\rho^{-2}}\cos^{2} \theta}
$$

Now, we look at the numerator. *Regardless of the value of $\theta$*, we have that the numerator will be between $-1$ and $1$. So, the numerator doesn't really move here : all the big stuff is in the denominator.

In the denominator, the point is that *$\mathit \rho$ is super super small*, so $\rho^{-2}$ is super super big. Therefore, if $\sin \theta \neq 0$, the contribution of $\rho^{-2}\sin^4 \theta$ can be made much much larger than the contribution of $\cos^2 \theta$ by simply taking $\rho$ small enough.

If $\sin \theta = 0$ then $\cos \theta = 1$ so the denominator is $1$,  but then the numerator is zero, so the given expression is zero.

Either way, you see , at least geometrically, that *independent of $\mathit \theta$, the given expression behaves very much like $0$ for $\mathit \rho$ chosen sufficiently small*.

Of course, other answers will suggest how  to approach this rigorously, but your takeaway should be this : as long as there's a "controlling/dominating term" (imagine a policeman trying to prevent people getting out of their houses during a curfew), there's not much that varying $\theta$ can get you : the misbehaviour of the changing $\theta$ is only so much.

Which, of course, is also the content of the famous squeeze principle or sandwich theorem of limits. From a rigorous point of view, the answer to these sort of questions is to identify bounds for the non-dominating terms, and use the squeeze principle, as the others have done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response!

Comment: You are welcome! Please read carefully the details : I like the fact that you have seen this limit geometrically and then deduced it did not exist , because it allows me to correct you and show you the geometric picture better.

Comment: I saved your comment, it was an amazing explanation. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos^{2}(\theta)=0$ then $sin^{2}(\theta) =1$ so you don't have  a $\frac 0 0$ situation.

Proof that the limit is $0$: $2xy^{2}\leq x^{2}+y^{4}$ so $|\frac {x^{2}y^{2}} {x^{2}+y^{4}}|\leq  \frac 1 2 |x| \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinates aren't necessary here. You may use the inequality

- $\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{a+b}{2}$ for $a,b\geq 0$
- $\Rightarrow x^2 + y^4 \geq 2\sqrt{x^2y^4}=2|x|y^2$.
- Note that if either $y= 0$ or $x= 0$ the expression is equal to zero anyways.

So, let's assume $xy \neq 0$:

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq \frac{x^2y^2}{2|x|y^2}=\frac{|x|}{2} \stackrel{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow}0$$