# Multivariable limits involving multiplication of two variables in the denominator

Tags: limits

I am currently enrolled in Calculus 3 at my university. We are defining limits, derivatives, integrals, etc. with multiple variables, a novel concept to me. I am especially confused about the following question:
$$\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (2, 0)} \frac{1-\cos y}{2xy^2}$$
I have tried using L'Hôpital's Rule, but seem to arrive at the same conclusion irregardless of how many times I take the derivative. Any tips to help me get going in the right direction?

This is my first time posting so sorry if any formatting or styling is incorrect.

Comment: Hint. $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (2, 0)} \frac{1-\cos y}{2xy^2}=\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^2}$. Then apply L'Hôpital's Rule two times.

Comment: Gotcha - so 1/8. That's a fascinating way to approach this problem (granted, from someone who's never really worked with multivariable limits). Is there a certain property that guarantees $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (2, 0)} \frac{1-cosy}{2xy^2}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{4} \lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (2,0)} \frac{1-cosy}{y^2}$? I suppose it's intuitive but, had you not mentioned it, I never would have thought of it.

Comment: In this case it suffices to use the definition of limit and its basic properties. Your limit is multivariable but here we can separate the variables and therefore the evaluation is very easy. See the following link for a "true" multivariable limit: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167078/multivariable-calculus-proving-that-this-limit-exists-with-polar-coordinates?rq=1

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your helpful breakdown! Sorry for it being such a trivial question - I'm still pretty new to multiple variables. Also, thank you for the link! That looks even more fun, can't wait to get there! :)